# update torndb connection timezone without spawning a new connection

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, tornado

Say you open up a new database connection on your API with torndb

```
db_conn = torndb.Connection(ip,
                            database,
                            user=user,
                            password=password,
                            time_zone="UTC",
                            charset="utf8")
```

Is it possible to, after the initial declaration in the code, edit the connections timezone to something else or is it required to spawn a new connection with your updated timezone.

I've tried accessing the torndb.Connection object with `db_conn.time_zone` but I run into `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'time_zone'`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change timezone of a connection. If you go through the [source code](https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb/blob/master/torndb.py#L82), you'll see that Torndb actually executes the `SET time_zone` command to set the timezone when the connection is created. And it provides no way to execute SQL commands (other than query commands, of course).

Comment: @xyres yea i've noticed that when i looked at the source, I found a solution though, will post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly change the timezone of the connection object afaik. What you can do though, is run a query whenever you need to change the timezone such as `SET time_zone = "foo/bar";` and execute it, and for as long as the connection session exists you can dynamically change timezones this way.